# getLastRow returns no result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this simple code to copy transposed range to the last row of another Sheet starting from column 14

```
   function copyAllInRange(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var destsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database')
    var destrow = destsheet.getLastRow()

    var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(53, 4, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getRange('54:54').getLastColumn());
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(destsheet.getRange(destrow,14),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);

    }
```

It returns zero results as it is. If I change destrow from the formula to simple 2 (that is the last empty row now), it works fine. Why it does not return last row index in the destination sheet?

Comment: Anton, does your target sheet have data in it? Because if it does not, the `getLastRow()` will return `0`, invalid row index for `getRange()` method.

Comment: yes, it has a header in the first row so should return 2. anyway, now it works

Comment: Anton, thank you for clarifiyng - I've noticed that Cooper gave the right answer, glad to hear it works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function copyAllInRange(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var destsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  var destrow = destsheet.getLastRow();
  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(53,4,sheet.getMaxRows()-52,sheet.getLastColumn()-3);//are really sure that you want to use getMaxRows() here cause that seems weird to me. 
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(destsheet.getRange(destrow + 1,14),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
}
```

Comment: ok. problem was in getMaxRows(). I can avoid it. Now I changed it to fixed amount of rows and script works as it should

Comment: You could perhaps use sheet.getDataRange().

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that `ss.getSheetByName('Database')` is returning `null` because `getLastRow()` will return 1 or a bigger number for any sheet.